# Vuejs bind class to row then later hide/show the row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a table where the user can hide rows, and keep them hidden as they delete other rows.

In my html I use vuejs to bind a class when rendering the table:

```
<tr v-for="item in mylist" :class="{'noFruits': (item.fruits.length == 0)}">
```

There is a user checkbox to hide rows with that class:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" v-model="showBlankFruits" @change="setBlankDisplay">Show Blank Fruits</label>
```

In my Vue instance, the checkbox executes a method to hide/show rows with that class via jquery to attach the css display property:

```
methods: {
  setBlankDisplay: function() {
    if (this.showBlankFruits) {
     $('.noFruits').css('display', '');
  } else {
     $('.noFruits').css('display', 'none');
  }
},
```

In my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c35058o5/), when a user deletes a row, the hidden row reappears. I see that attaching styles with jquery in this instance is not good... does anyone have a suggestion for a better method?

Comment: there are components for class/style bindings in vuejs. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing Vue and jQuery is not recommended, as you can do pretty much everything just using Vue and you don't get any conflicting operations that don't know what the other library/framework is doing.

The following will show the row if either the fruits array length is truthy, in other words not 0, or if showBlankFruits is true:

```
<tr v-for="item in mylist" v-show="item.fruits.length || showBlankFruits">
```

The following will toggle showBlankFruits when clicking the checkbox:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" v-model="showBlankFruits">Show Blank Fruits</label>
```

Full code example:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qqp3tdad/3/)

Answer (score 2):

You can also write something like this.
I've used computed and removed the jQuery part completely.
You must declare data as a function instead of an data object (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function)

You do not need to call the **mounted** method to set the initial state. It's already set with your data object.
In your code, you have to call mounted, because jQuery can only hide the results, when the DOM is loaded.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      showBlankFruits: true,
      mylist: [
        {'user': 'Alice', 'fruits': [{'name': 'apple'}]},
        {'user': 'Bob', 'fruits': [{'name': 'orange'}]},
        {'user': 'Charlie', 'fruits': []},
        {'user': 'Denise', 'fruits': [{'name': 'apple'}, {'name': 'orange'}]},
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    list() {
      return this.mylist.filter(item => (item.fruits.length > 0 && !this.showBlankFruits) || (item.fruits.length === 0 && this.showBlankFruits))
    },
  },
  methods: {
    delItem(item) {
      let index = this.mylist.indexOf(item);
      if (index > -1) {
        this.mylist.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="showBlankFruits">Show Blank Fruits</label>
  <br> <br>
  <table>
    <tr> <th class="col">User</th> <th class="col">Fruits</th> <th class="col"></th> </tr>
    <tr v-for="item in list">
      <td>{{ item.user }}</td>
      <td> <span v-for="f in item.fruits"> {{ f.name }} </span> </td>
      <td> <button @click="delItem(item)">Delete</button> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I prefer doing it this way over style bindings like in @cstricklan solution. Using a computed which filters the data makes the component more testable.

Comment: It's *required* for data to be a function for *components*. It's not "recommended" that it be a function anywhere to my knowledge for root Vue instances. In fact, the documentation walks you through using objects from the [very beginning](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Declarative-Rendering).

Comment: I’ve written “recommended” because in this example he’s using a single instance and it not breaks the application. But you’re right! I’ll update my answer.

Comment: Filter conditional can be simplified, `item.fruits.length || this.showBlankFruits`

Comment: @LeeComstock yeah you're right, if you want to show the complete list everytime with or without empty fruits. I tought that Andrew wants not both at the same time, because the checkbox label says "Show Blank Fruits" and not "Show with Blank Fruits"

Comment: I was looking to show all or show filtered, I should have named my checkbox "Include Blank Fruits in Display"... so I think the v-show conditional from @LeeComstock works for me. I didn't declare data as a function since I am not using components in my project (at least not yet). All these give answers give me good approaches, thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

This is a great example of the power for declarative rendering rather than using DOM manipulation in components.  The problem you are running into is when the Vue engine re-renders your list it doesn't know about the manual manipulation of elemets you did in the `setBlankDisplay` method.  The way to get around that is to use component logic in the definition of the view itself, sort of like you did to set the `noFruits` class in the first place.

So, I propose you get rid of `setBlankDisplay` and replace it with the method:

```
itemDisplay(item) {
    if (item.fruits.length === 0 && !this.showBlankFruits) {
    return 'none';
  }
  return '';
},
```

Then you can reference it in the definition of your `tr` elements linked to a css `display` property, like so:

```
<tr v-for="item in mylist" :class="{'noFruits': (item.fruits.length == 0)}" :style="{display: itemDisplay(item)}">
```

I've updated the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pktovb1w/) with this modification, showing that the state of hidden fruits remains when other items are deleted.

Take this as a general example of the dangers of using jquery to change the state of the view.  Every effort should be taken to define the entire view in terms of component logic.